# Source to Target horribly fails with dynamic creation

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

This happens when I'm dynamically adding sources and targets:

[image: Example]

What I'm doing here is creating dynamic entities on double-click inside the container. In those entities the user can add `sources` (left) and `targets` (right). The problem is that when I try to connect a source with a target that it somehow links to the original `parent` ID of the entity. There is no invisible `target` where the grey line goes (on the left Plus-sign, the big grey Dot is the starting point). Here's my code:

```
<body>
    <div id="pContainer"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            jsPlumb.Defaults.PaintStyle = {
                lineWidth: 4,
                strokeStyle: 'rgba(123, 123, 123, 1)',
            };
            jsPlumb.Defaults.LogEnabled = true;

            var i = 1;

            $('#pContainer').dblclick(function(evt) {
                var newEntity = $('<div>').attr('id', 'entity' + i).addClass('item');

                newEntity.css({
                    'top': evt.pageY,
                    'left': evt.pageX,
                });

                var title = $('<div>').addClass('title').text('Activity ' + i);
                var sockets = $('<div>').addClass('sockets');
                var socketsLeft = $('<span>').addClass('socketsLeft');
                var leftAdd = $('<i>').addClass('fa fa-plus-circle');
                var socketsRight = $('<span>').addClass('socketsRight');
                var rightAdd = $('<i>').addClass('fa fa-plus-circle');

                var clear = $('<div>').addClass('clear');

                socketsLeft.append(leftAdd);
                socketsRight.append(rightAdd);
                sockets.append(socketsLeft);
                sockets.append(socketsRight);

                newEntity.append(title);
                newEntity.append(sockets);
                newEntity.append(clear);

                jsPlumb.draggable(newEntity, {
                    containment: 'parent',
                });

                newEntity.click(function(evt) {
                    $('div[id^="entity"]').css({
                        'box-shadow': 'none',
                    });
                    $(this).css({
                        'box-shadow': '0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(47, 169, 240, 0.8)',
                    });
                });

                /*newEntity.dblclick(function(evt) {
                    jsPlumb.detachAllConnections($(this));
                    $(this).remove();
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                });*/

                $(leftAdd).click(function(evt) {
                    var _this = $(this);

                    var connect = $('<div>').addClass('connect');
                    var tagName = $('<div>').addClass('tagName').text('Fieldname 1');

                    jsPlumb.makeTarget(connect, {
                        parent: _this.parent(),
                        dropOptions: {
                            hoverClass: 'dragHover'
                        },
                        anchor: 'Continuous',
                        connector: 'Flowchart',
                        paintStyle: {
                            fillStyle: 'rgba(123, 123, 123, 1)',
                            radius: 1,
                        },
                    });

                    $(this).closest('.socketsLeft').prepend('<br>');
                    $(this).closest('.socketsLeft').prepend(tagName);
                    $(this).closest('.socketsLeft').prepend(connect);
                });

                $(rightAdd).click(function(evt) {
                    var _this = $(this);

                    var connect = $('<div>').addClass('connect');
                    var tagName = $('<div>').addClass('tagName').text('Fieldname 1');

                    jsPlumb.makeSource(connect, {
                        parent: _this.parent(),
                        anchor: 'Continuous',
                        connector: 'Flowchart',
                        paintStyle: {
                            fillStyle: 'rgba(123, 123, 123, 1)',
                            radius: 10,
                        },
                    });

                    $(this).closest('.socketsRight').prepend('<br>');
                    $(this).closest('.socketsRight').prepend(connect);
                    $(this).closest('.socketsRight').prepend(tagName);
                });

                newEntity.hover(function(evt) {
                    //$(this).toggleClass('shadow');
                });

                $('#pContainer').append(newEntity);

                i++;
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Extra image:

[image: Extra Image]

Comment: Try setting dynamic ID's at the time of DIV creation.
`var connect = $('<div id='+random_num+'>').addClass('connect');`

Comment: Thanks for the comment Pruthvi. Sadly it doesn't change the effect. The odd thing is that the `target` does actually get a small grey stripe (pixels) at its location. Also when I move the `target` element the lines starts to move. For some reason the drawing fails.

Comment: Can you reproduce your code in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Here it is :) http://jsfiddle.net/C5ZLk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated your **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5ZLk/6/)**

You need to set common container for all connections else will result in weird connections. Include below code:

```
jsPlumb.Defaults.Container = $("#pContainer");
```

When you make the `connect` object as source and target then remove `jsPlumb.draggable()` for entity and try to make use of customised jQuery draggable as given below:

```
newEntity.draggable({
         drag:function(e){
              $(this).find('._jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor_').each(function(i,e){                            
                      jsPlumb.repaint($(e));
              });       
         }
});
```

UPDATE:
You can restrict the endpoint side by using `anchor` option. Code:

```
jsPlumb.makeSource(connect, {
            parent: connect,
            anchor: 'Right',    // Restrict endpoint side
            connector: 'Flowchart',
            paintStyle: {
                fillStyle: 'rgba(123, 123, 123, 1)',
                radius: 10,
            },
});
```

lly for Left hand side.

Final **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C5ZLk/6/)** including the draggable option fix!

Comment: Thanks Pruthvi. Any idea how to make the `source` actually link to the socket instead of the parent block? The `target` seems to link correctly only.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you Pruthvi. One last by-the-by question. Can I force the line to avoid the `#entity` blocks or let the line only land on the left/right side of the socket? The line can fall over the `entity` block, which gives a weird user experience.

Comment: @Allendar Sorry didn't get you. Try to explain with an image!

Comment: Added extra image to the original question.The green border would be a no-go zone for lines. The red line would be a result of the avoiding-line to reach the `target`.

Comment: @PruthviBharadwaj Thanks for the final fiddle. It looks clean and helped me a lot.

Comment: Magnificent! Thanks so much Pruthvi!